# The string is getting the wrong value

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I am trying to build a string like `11 11` but I am facing problem  I am getting for `start` the following string `98 11` and not `11 11`.

How can I fix that?

I appreciate any help.

```
Character number = newName.charAt(2); //here number is 1
Character numberBefore = newName.charAt(1); //here numberBefore is 1

try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(path+File.separator+newName);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
  boolean shouldPrint = false;
  while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = scanner.nextLine();

  if(numberBefore >0 ){
    String start= number+number+" "+number+number; //here start is `98 11`
  }
```

Comment: This should work: String start= number+""+number+" "+number+""+number; or String start= ""+number+number+" "+number+number;

Comment: it works for me like this `String start = new StringBuilder().append(number).append(number).append(' ').append(number).append(number).toString();` too :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is due to the associativity of `+`.

This:

```
String start= number+number+" "+number+number;
```

is effectively:

```
String start = (((number + number) + " ") + number) + number;
```

So you're getting `number + number` (which is performing numeric promotion to `int`) and *then* string concatenation.

It sounds like you want:

```
String numberString = String.valueOf(number);
String start = numberString + numberString + " " + numberString + numberString;
```

Or alternatively:

```
String start = String.format("%0c%0c %0c%0c", number);
```

Comment: Is there any way to convert `char` to string to get this `if(numberBefore >0 ){}`  Statement to work ? I tried like this but I am getting the wrong value `int numberBefore = (int) newName.charAt(1);`

Comment: @MrPencil: That's an entirely separate problem - it sounds like you don't want to convert a `char` to `String` but to an `int` instead... I suggest you do some research, and ask a new question if you still have issues.

Answer (score 0):

yes this is because of associativity of +

you can try the below code also

```
String c1 =Character.toString(number);
String s =c1+c1+" "+c1+c1;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        String newName = "111";
    Character number = newName.charAt(2); // here number is 1
    Character numberBefore = newName.charAt(1); // here numberBefore is 1

    if (Character.getNumericValue(numberBefore) > 0) {  // checking against numeric rather than ascii
        System.out.println("ASCII value of char " + (int) number); // ASCII code for '1' = 49
        String start = String.valueOf(number) + String.valueOf(number) + " " + number + number; // here start is `98 11`
        System.out.println(start);
    }
}
```